# Android Universal Image Loader Compiler Error

Tags: android, url, compiler-errors, universal-image-loader

I'm a beginner in programing and all i want to do is compile this simple project I'm working on but I continue to get this same error, the code and error log are below.

ImageGridActivity.java

```
....

imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted() {
                    // do nothing
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
                    imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

                    switch (failReason) {
                        case MEMORY_OVERFLOW:
                            imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete() {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });

            return imageView;
        }
....
```

Here is the error log. I'm using Android Studio for this project.

```
GridViewerBro/BRO/src/main/java/com/example/bro/ImageGridActivity.java:97: error: no suitable method found for displayImage(String,ImageView,DisplayImageOptions,<anonymous com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoadingListener>)
            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                       ^
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageView,DisplayImageOptions,ImageLoadingListener,ImageLoadingProgressListener) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageView,DisplayImageOptions,ImageLoadingListener) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoadingListener> cannot be converted to ImageLoadingListener by method invocation conversion)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageView,ImageLoadingListener) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageView,DisplayImageOptions) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageView) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageAware,DisplayImageOptions,ImageLoadingListener,ImageLoadingProgressListener) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageAware,DisplayImageOptions,ImageLoadingListener) is not applicable
      (actual argument ImageView cannot be converted to ImageAware by method invocation conversion)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageAware,DisplayImageOptions) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageAware,ImageLoadingListener) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ImageLoader.displayImage(String,ImageAware) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error messages, we can filter out other possibilities. And this is the most closest error.

"method ImageLoader.displayImage**(String,ImageView,DisplayImageOptions,ImageLoadingListener)** is not applicable (actual argument  **cannot be converted to ImageLoadingListener by method invocation conversion**)"

Seems it is really complaints about "com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoadingListener"

Comment: I have it as com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoadingListener

Comment: Hmm, I still suspect that is the problem. If possible, can you show me the downloadable link? I know github has the project, but the ImageLoadingListener is inside "core/library" folder rather than "core" folder.

Comment: Can you look at their source code? ImageLoadingListener is from core/listener folder rather than core folder.

Comment: Yes its in core instead of core/listener as you've identified,

Comment: Can you check whether you have two versions of Image-Loader library in your project? It may cause this problem because you are loading the same class from two libraries.

Comment: Seems you have many versions of support library. You need to have a common support library, so that when your other libraries need use support library too, they can point to your common support library. The way to do it, is to add support lib into your project. Then delete support lib from your other library projects. After that make a dependency from your other library projects pointing to your support lib.

Comment: Awesome. If you can mark the answer correct it would be great.

Comment: @Ethan I am having the same problem and it seems that your solution is the way to go. However, how can I delete the duplicated library from my other library? The library that contains it only shows up in build/intermediates.

Comment: @jeraldo Can you check whether you have libraries that are conflicting? In other words, do you have libraries that has the same name, in which case, you need to only keep one.

Comment: Yes I saw libraries that are the same but different version. One in my app module and the other in one of my libraries. Solution was to use the library with the latest version and update my imports.